# How to write absolute value in c

Tags: c

I know the solution is ugly and technically incorrect but I don't understand why the code doesn't work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int u;

    scanf("%d", &u);
    printf("absValue = %u\n", u);

return 0;
}
```

%u specifies an unsigned decimal character but when I input a negative value, it gives

```c
absValue = 4294967293
```

Alternatively, with the if command, how to convert the negative sign to positive?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n < 0) {
        printf("absValue = -%d\n", n);
    } else {
        printf("absValue = %d\n", n);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the minus sign next to the variable name, e.g. `-n`

Comment: `"%u"` is for `unsigned int` as you know. But you use a `signed int` variable. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Both your solutions show a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of the format string. It controls only the presentation of the values that are already there; it cannot alter the values themselves. In particular, when you write `%u`, the corresponding value must already be unsigned; it cannot change a signed value to an unsigned. Similarly, a minus in front of `%d` is just that - a literal dash that does not change the value inside variable `n` being printed.

Comment: When you jam a signed value into an unsigned variable (or by printf trickery, try to interpret a signed value as if it were unsigned), the value you get is *not* the absolute value.  Typically the value you get is the [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  Very different.

Comment: BTW, there is an `abs` function that you can use to find the absolute value of an integer variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest solution in your first piece of code is to change the `printf` statement as follows:

```
    printf("absValue = %u\n", (unsigned)((u<0)?-u:u));
```

This will print the absolute value of `u`. The type conversion `(unsigned)` ensures that the data type is as expected by `printf`. The statement `(u<0)?-u:u` uses the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) to select the value `-u` if the condition (`u<0`) is true and `u` if the condition is false (i.e. `u>=0`).

The problem in your code is that `u` is a signed integer which means its value is stored using the [Two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in 4 bytes(*) and `printf` is not intelligent. When you tell `printf` to display an unsigned integer, then `printf` will take the 4 bytes holding `u` and interpret them as an unsigned integer. Since negative numbers in Two's complement are stored as large positive integers, that is the result you see.

(*) The use of Two's complement and the `int` size of 4 is machine-dependent, but common.

Comment: Can you explain the conditional operator? If the OP is struggling with this, I highly doubt he's used the conditional operator before.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I actually considered this, but decided that the type mismatch is only a problem if `int`and `unsigned` have different sizes or representation of positive value. None of which I have ever seen. So for simplicity I left it out. Maybe a bad decision, so it is good that you have mentioned it here.

Comment: @Blastfurnace And you are absolutely right. I usually speak against sacrificing correctness for simplicity, so I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @yhyrcanus My thought was to leave it as an exercise for the OP, but now I added it anyway :-).

Comment: "`u` is an unsigned integer which means its value is stored using the Two's complement representation" -- huh?? Only negative signed values are stored as Two's Compliment. Positive signed and unsigned values are simply stored using their normal bit representation. (but I think I understand what you are explaining..., the blanket statement is just a bit off)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It was a typo (unsigned should be signed). I corrected it now in the answer. Thank you for noticing this which I agree was quite disturbing to the understanding.

Comment: Sure, it was just something that caught my eye reading through the answer.

Comment: @nielsen *It was a typo (unsigned should be signed)* I'm not so sure about that, given that `INT_MIN` causes problems with `int u` when you apply `-u`. Someone with a better grasp than I do of ["the integer promotions"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p3) in this case probably can answer that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are right that the solution excludes the special case of `INT_MIN` if the system uses Two's complement. I will leave it an an exercise to the OP to convert `u` to a `long long` before the `printf()` statement which would normally take care of that special case (it does when int is 32 bits, generally but we would need to check that `sizeof(long long)>sizeof(int)` since that is not guaranteed). Otherwise, your  alternative of using `double` is a possibility even though the exact properties are not specified, so it is not guaranteed that we will not lose digits in the conversion.

Comment: @nielsen Seems like a language-lawyer question:  Is there a strictly conforming way to get the absolute value of an `int` without loss of precision?  Because neither `long long` nor `double` are guaranteed to have more bits of precision than `int` does.  Does the unary `-` cause a direct promotion to `unsigned`?  If so, your solution does seem to work.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `printf("absValue = %u\n", n < 0 ? (unsigned)  (-1 - n) + 1u : (unsigned) n);` should work.  Perhaps other more simple ones do too.

Comment: @nielsen `- INT_MIN` is UB as you mentioned.  Conversion to `long long, long double` is not needed to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can also use [the standard C function `abs()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.1) (or one of its related functions):

> **7.22.6.1 The abs, labs and llabs functions**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>      #include <stdlib.h>
>      int abs(int j);
>      long int labs(long int j);
>      long long int llabs(long long int j);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `abs`, `labs`, and `llabs` functions compute the absolute value of
>   an integer `j`. If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `abs`, `labs`, and `llabs`, functions return the absolute value.
>
> **Footnotes**
>
> The absolute value of the most negative number cannot be represented
>   in two's complement.

Note the footnote "The absolute value of the most negative number cannot be represented in two's complement." and "If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  Strictly speaking, you'd likely need to use `long long int` and `llabs()` to avoid undefined behavior in converting `INT_MIN` to a positive value, assuming a 32-bit `int` value, and `long` is often 32-bits, even on 64-bit Windows.

However, since `double` values are likely implemented in [IEEE format with 53 bits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), a 32-bit `int` value can be converted to `double` with no loss of precision, so you can use [the `fabs()` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.2) to get the absolute value of a 32-bit `int` value in one call:

> **7.12.7.2 The fabs functions**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <math.h>
>     double fabs(double x);
>     float fabsf(float x);
>     long double fabsl(long double x);
> ```
>
> The `fabs` functions compute the absolute value of a floating-point
>   number `x`.

So your code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int u;

    scanf("%d", &u);
    printf("absValue = %u\n", (unsigned) fabs((double) u));

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in `(unsigned) fabs((double) u)`, casting `u` to `double` is not strictly necessary, as the `int` value will be implicitly converted to a `double` because of the `double fabs(double)` function prototype from `stdlib.h`.  But the cast back to `unsigned` is **exremely** necessary to pass the `unsigned int` value you want to pass to `printf()`.

You could also do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int u;

    scanf("%d", &u);
    unsigned int absValue = fabs(u);
    printf("absValue = %u\n", absValue);

    return 0;
}
```

That works because `unsigned int absValue` is **explicitly** an `unsigned int`.

Also, on modern CPUs, conversion between `int` and `double` is usually done by a single relatively fast instruction.

Comment: Since the integer abs() functions (abs, labs, llabs) only support the basic types (like int) they are not cross-platform for the extended types such as int32_t and the like. I might write logic for one platform that works with one of the integer abs functions, but it might not work on another platform. But I think your fabs() trick would work cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't convert the strings, but rather expects them converted. I would generally prefer to use the standard [abs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/abs.html) function which is declared in `stdlib.h`. This uses [strtol](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) to convert an argument to a `long` then convert that to an `int`. *Nota bene*, that, for example, if your machine uses two's-complements, calling `abs(INT_MIN)` produces undefined behaviour and should be dealt with. (Edited: error detection now complies with non-POSIX systems; see comments.)

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* perror, printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol, abs */
#include <limits.h> /* INT_MIN, INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno, ERANGE */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int u;
    long input;
    char *end;

    /* Require one argument. */
    if(argc != 2) return printf("Usage <number>\n"), EXIT_SUCCESS;

    /* `input` is converted from `argv[1]`, if it's 0, check that it actually
     read 0; check to see garbage characters at the end; check to see if the
     `input` is a) less then `INT_MIN`; b) also if `-INT_MAX < 0`, check that
     it is not lower than this value, because that will lead to undefined
     `abs`; c) more then `INT_MAX` -> if so, set `ERRNO` and enter the if. */
    if(    ((input = strtol(argv[1], &end, 0)) == 0 && end == argv[1])
        || (*end != '\0' && (errno = EILSEQ, 1))
        || ((input < INT_MIN || (-INT_MAX < 0 && input < -INT_MAX)
        || input > INT_MAX) && (errno = ERANGE, 1))    )
        return perror("Input"), EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* We are pretty sure this cast is safe, now: `int abs(int)`. */
    u = abs((int)input);
    printf("absValue(%ld) = %d\n", input, u);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Checking edge cases,

```
bin/abs 2147483647
absValue(2147483647) = 2147483647
bin/abs 2147483648
Input: Result too large
bin/abs -2147483648
Input: Result too large
bin/abs -2147483647
absValue(-2147483647) = 2147483647
bin/abs
Usage <number>
bin/abs 0x10
absValue(16) = 16
bin/abs asdf
Input: Invalid argument
bin/abs 1a
Input: Illegal byte sequence
```

Comment: `(input = strtol(argv[1], 0, 0)) == 0 && errno` test is unclear.  `strtol()` is not specified in C to set `errno` should no conversion occur.  With `char *endptr; .... strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 0)`, `if (argv[1] == endptr)` is the specified no conversion test.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html "If no conversion could be performed, 0 shall be returned [POSIX2017]  and errno may be set to [EINVAL]. If the value of base is not supported, 0 shall be returned and errno shall be set to [EINVAL]." I see no other way to discriminate between 0 as a valid input and as an error. Good point about `endptr`, if one wanted to be really strict, `argv[1] == endptr || *endptr != '\0'`?

Comment: that portion of the spec is in Posix C, not  the C standard.  This question is only tagged C.  `argv[1] == endptr` is a good and sufficient test for "no conversion"

Answer (score 1):

> How to write absolute value in c?

The shortest solution :

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

printf("absValue = %d\n", abs(u));  // clear and concise - yet see below
```

---

Both `printf("%d\n", abs(u));` and `printf("%u\n", (unsigned)((u<0)?-u:u));` suffer the same problem: [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++) (UB) when `n == INT_MIN`<sup>1</sup>.  The signed negation of `INT_MIN` is the UB.

At least `abs(u)` is clear, unlike `(unsigned)((u<0)?-u:u)`.

---

To print the absolute value of an `int`, code could negate negative values with:
`(-1 - n) + 1u` or
`-(unsigned)n` or
`0u - n`
... and end up with an `unsigned`.<sup>2</sup>

I'd go for the simplest when a full range `|int|` is sought.

```
printf("absValue = %u\n", n < 0 ? 0u - n : (unsigned) n);
```

---

Using `long`, `long long` or `double` poses their own troubles and portability.  None   warranted here.

---

<sup>1</sup> when `int` is 2's complement encoded - *very* common.

<sup>2</sup> C specified `UINT_MAX >= INT_MAX`.  In the *very* rare implementations today, `INT_MAX == INT_MAX` is possible and code needs to resort to a wider type when `int` is non 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

this is a function to get the absolute value of a number without using abs() function.

```
int abs_value(int *a){
    return *a < 0 ? -*a: *a;
}
```

If you want to get the absolute difference between two numbers, here's how:

```
int abs_diff (int *a, int*b) {
    return *a > *b ? *a - *b : *b - *a;
}
```

Comment: You can use `abs()` from `stdlib.h`

Comment: Yes, this is without using abs() from stdlib.h

Comment: Should `a` point to a value of `INT_MIN`, `-*a` is a problem.  `*a - *b` is prone to overflow.